# Secure ADB connection over network

Tags: adb, security, networking, ssh, vpn

I am using Geniatech ATV Android Set Top Boxes running android 4.2.2 for a current project. I might put some of those devices in public places like shopping centers. These boxes are connected to the local network there by cable or wireless.

I have a VPN connection to ssh remotely into the boxes (using debian kit) and on the boxes USB debugging is enabled, so that i have ADB access, which I use for chrome browser observation as well as for updating or installing new applications.

The problem is that everyone on the same local network as the box can also use adb to connect to the boxes and then have full access to everything, which is a big security problem.

What I want to do is restrict the interface of adb to only work over the vpn connection.

Alternatively I need a way to stop and start the adb daemon using my ssh connection to the box. The problem here is that I only connect to a debian kit instance running on the same box, which uses the same filesystem but doesn't have access to the start or stop adb commands.

Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this? I can't find a lot of information on this special requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing was starting another ssh server in the android environment using another port, from which I then can stop and start the adb daemon. Not nice, but it gets the job done.